# How to get a html text inside tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I extract data from example HTML with `beautifulsoup`?

```html
<Tag1>
    <message code="able to extract text from here"/>
    <text value="able to extract text that is here"/>
    <htmlText>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;some thing &lt;lite&gt;OR&lt;/lite&gt;get exact data from here&lt;/p&gt;]]&gt;</htmlText>
</Tag1>
```

I tried both `.findall` and `.get_text`, however I am not able to extract the text values from `htmlText` element.

Expected output:

```
some thing ORget exact data from here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's are the steps you need to make:

```py
# firstly, select all "htmlText" elements
soup.select("htmlText")


# secondly, iterate over all of them
for result in soup.select("htmlText"):
    # further code


# thirdly, use another BeautifulSoup() object to parse the data
# otherwise you can't access <p>, <lite> elements data
# since they are unreachable to first BeautifulSoup() object
for result in soup.select("htmlText"):
    final = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml")


# fourthly, grab all <p> elements AND their .text -> "p.text"
for result in soup.select("htmlText"):
    final = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml").p.text
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/how-to-get-a-html-text-inside-tag-through-beautiful-soup-py#main.py) (*use the most readable*):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html = """
<Tag1>
    <message code="able to extract text from here"/>
    <text value="able to extract text that is here"/>
    <htmlText>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;some thing &lt;lite&gt;OR&lt;/lite&gt;get exact data from here&lt;/p&gt;]]&gt;</htmlText>
</Tag1>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")


# BeautifulSoup inside BeautifulSoup
unreadable_soup = BeautifulSoup(BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").select_one('htmlText').text, "lxml").p.text
print(unreadable_soup)


example_1 = BeautifulSoup(soup.select_one('htmlText').text, "lxml").p.text
print(text_1)


# wihtout hardcoded list slices
for result in soup.select("htmlText"):
    example_2 = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml").p.text
    print(example_2)


# or one liner
example_3 = ''.join([BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml").p.text for result in soup.select("htmlText")])
print(example_3)


# output
'''
some thing ORget exact data from here
some thing ORget exact data from here
some thing ORget exact data from here
some thing ORget exact data from here
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use BeautifulSoup twice, first extract the `htmlText` element and then parse the contents. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html = """
<Tag1>
    <message code="able to extract text from here"/>
    <text value="able to extract text that is here"/>
    <htmlText>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;some thing &lt;lite&gt;OR&lt;/lite&gt;get exact data from here&lt;/p&gt;]]&gt;</htmlText>
</Tag1>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for tag1 in soup.find_all("tag1"):
    cdata_html = tag1.htmltext.text
    cdata_soup = BeautifulSoup(cdata_html, "lxml")
    
    print(cdata_soup.p.text)
```

Which would display:

```
some thing ORget exact data from here
```

Note: [lxml](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) needs to also be installed using `pip install lxml`. BeautifulSoup will automatically import this.